# How to find a parent in the tree

Tags: scheme

I am new to scheme and I need a help. How to find a parent of the element in the tree?

```
;; returns left subtree of node 
(define (left node)
  (if (null? node) '()
      (cadr node)))

;; returns right subtree of node
(define (right node)
  (if (null? node) '()
      (caddr node)))
```

I think it should be like that:

```
(define (parent element tree)

   (cond
        ((null? tree) )
        (car tree)
        ((< val (car tree)) (parent val (left tree))) ; 
        ((> val (car tree)) (parent val (right tree))); 


    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra argument to parent

```
(define (parent element parent-of-tree tree)
  ...)
```

The root element has no parent, so call `parent` like this:

```
   (parent element #f tree)
```

When you go deeper in the tree, pass the parent in parent-of-tree.
For example the (< val (car tree)) becomes:

```
   ((< val (car tree)) (parent val tree (left tree)))
```